# Rotating a tree in Java

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to rotate my tree in java.
Say I have the tree below and I want to rotate left or right around node 2.  I have tried googling it, but what I really need is a step by step guide on the operations needed to preform the rotation, etc (1. set left child to x), it does not need to be in code.
If anyone would care to explain, or have a page that does this I would be forever thankful.

[image: tree example]

Comment: i think this is what you looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638005/avl-tree-rotation-in-java and this picture from wikipedia could also be helpful: [Tree_Rotations.gif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation#mediaviewer/File:Tree_Rotations.gif)

Comment: Are you looking for help with rotating red-black trees in particular? You didn't say, but the picture kind of implies that you might be.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "guide" to do such rotation. There are a few options, for example:

[image]

another option:

[image]

another option:

[image]

etc.

Comment: This is an AVL tree, so the last 2 cases are illegal states.

Comment: @Obicere the question doesn't mention AVL trees.

Comment: Just the coloring system alone suggests an RB tree or an AVL tree. That is fairly standard.

Answer (score 0):

just type height balanced tree in google that will give you all information about rotate you can rotate this by just set all the link and one important thing is that you link is important if you can not set link appropriately then you will lost your data or go in some loop